# Issue with HideCol/ShowCol in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid to display the data. I am using hidecol/showcol to hide/show columns in the jqGrid. ShrinkToFit is true.

First I am hiding the column using hideCol. When user select one option I am displaying the hidden column using showCol method. The problem is each time when I call showCol it is reducing the width of that column.

Sample Code:

```
var mydata = [{name1:"abcdef",name2:"abcdef",name3:"abcdef"},
{name1:"abcdef",name2:"abcdef",name3:"abcdef"},
{name1:"abcdef",name2:"abcdef",name3:"abcdef"},
{name1:"abcdef",name2:"abcdef",name3:"abcdef"},
{name1:"abcdef",name2:"abcdef",name3:"abcdef"},
{name1:"abcdef",name2:"abcdef",name3:"abcdef"}];
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({ data: mydata,
datatype: 'local',
height: 300,
rowNum: 30,
rowList: [10,20,30], 
colNames:['Name1','Name2', 'Name3'], 
colModel:[ {name:'name1',index:'name1', width:250}, 
{name:'name2',index:'name2', width:225}, 
{name:'name3',index:'name3', width:250}], 
pager: '#pager2', 
viewrecords: true, 
sortorder: "desc",   
hidegrid: false                          
}).navGrid('#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:true},
{},{},{},{});}  
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid().showCol("name1"); //show col         
jQuery("#list2").jqGrid().hideCol("name1"); //hide col
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the same problem which I has recently. I described the bug with my suggestions to fix it in the trirand forum [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-width-not-adjusted-in-showcolhidecol-in-case-of-shrinktofit-false/#p24098). The problem is already [fixed](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/4100e63d9f83a819127271a6eb58dadeb6b57060) in the code on the [github](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/).

I recommend you to look additionally on [another my suggestion](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/performance-improvement-in-hidecol-and-showcol-for-grid-with-many-rows/#p24277) which improved performance of `showCol` and `hideCol` methods. The suggestions are [included](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/commit/85384f9721b3b6ce868a6a99d97d519a81dfec0a) in the github code of jqGrid.

You can make the same changes in the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`.

Comment: I tried with these changes now it is reducing the width of the grid. Each time when I select hide or show it is reducing the grid width. With old code it was reducing only the column width and the grid width remains same.

Comment: @Sandy: You wrote "reducing". Does it means that the problem still not solved? In the case you could edit your question and append it with the code which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The problem still exists. Each time when show/hide a column, the grid will shrink.

Comment: @Sandy: You should post the demo which can be used to reproduce the problem. It can be that the bug exists in the combination of the settings which you use.

Comment: Added sample code. You can reproduce the issue by showing/hiding a column. Each time when you show/hide a column it will shrinks the grid width.

Comment: @Sandy: Sorry, but you are wrong. You can see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ShrinkingOfWidth.htm) that all work correct. The width of the columns are: 244px, 219px and 244px and will not changed even after 100 times of showing and hiding of the column. I used jqGrid version 4.3.1 in the demo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is working with jqGrid 4.3.1. I was using jqGrid 3.8.

Comment: @Sandy: You are welcome! You should better use the version where the bug is fixed.

Comment: @Oleg: I have the same problem, and I think the issue is not fixed. I tested with jqGrid 4.3.1 and 4.3.2. It looks like problem occurs when horizontal scrollbar is present. In this scenario, on each show/hide column grid will shrink by 18px (width of the scrollOffset). In case scrollbar is not preset, there is no shrinkage. In case I am right, you should be able to reproduce it easily in your demo.

Comment: @Oleg: Little correction to my previous comment: It is not horizontal scrollbar, but vertical. I tested it on demo page Oleg provided by adding more rows into the grid so that scrollbar is showing, and indeed shrinking is happening. I temporary fixed the issue in my case by re-setting original grid width on 'show' (until bug is fixed in jqgrid).